# According to the Elsewhere Principle, can a syntactic rule block a morphological one, or a morphological rule a phonological one?

Tags: phonology, morphology, generative-grammar, morphosyntax, minimalism

I read up on the [Elsewhere Principle](https://www.thoughtco.com/elsewhere-principle-linguistics-1690586). In the linked article two examples are given:

1. The *syntactic* comparative "*more* + adjective" can be overruled by the *morphological* comparative "adjective+*er*" for (most) short adjectives.
2. The *morphological* plural /-z/ can be overruled by specific *phonological* mapping rules, e.g. P(TOOTH PLURAL) = /teeth/ (P(X) is the phonological realization of X).

Am I right in recognizing some minimalist influence here in that both examples are in the same direction of syntax → morphology → phonology?

Are there examples of this principle in the other direction?

Comment: Phonological bonds are stronger than morphological ones, which are stronger than syntactic ones. Rather like atoms and molecules; the farther apart two items are, and the more boundaries there are between them, the less likely they are to influence each other.

Comment: @jlawler thanks, that was my intuition, but I wanted to confirm.

Comment: You're welcome. Oh, and I can't guarantee that this has anything to do with the Elsewhere Principle. Consult your confessor.